# Ball collision in Java

Tags: java, collision

I am making a game where a ball goes and collects other balls.
I have written a collision detector, but I am finding that it is a little off kilter.
If the controlled ball is about 10 pixels to the right of the ball to be collected, it will still register a collision.

If the user's ball is on the left side of the ball to be collected, the collision works well.
Could someone please explain why this is happening and/or suggest a fix? Thanks!

Here is my collision detector:

```
private void checkForCollision(UserBall b) {
    int ballX = b.getX();
    int ballY = b.getY();
    int ballR = b.getRadius();
    int a = x - ballX;
    int bb = y - ballY;
    int collide =radius + ballR;

    if (a*a + bb*bb <=collide*collide){
        performAction(b);
        createNew= true;
    }
}
```

Comment: where are `x` and `y` coming from? You never define them anywhere in this code.

Comment: Change time between computes and speed of balls (lower speed, smaller time intervals). Calculate next position of particles after collision detection. More questions...

Comment: Are the `ballX` and `ballY` coordinates the center of the ball, or the upper left corner? If you are drawing the ball with the `drawArc`, `fillArc`, `drawOval`, or `fillOval` methods of `Graphics`, then the `x` and `y` parameters are the upper left corner of the shape.

Comment: If x and y are the center of the ball, I think this code snippet is correct.

Comment: (x and y are the coordinates of the collected ball)

Wait so ballX and ballY are the top left of the ball!? No wonder all my collisions are bad. I learnt that they are the center from a YouTube video, I guess it must have been wrong.

The ball is actually just an image, it isn't from Java Graphics.

Comment: It all works great now.

David Conrad can you write that as an answer so I can mark it for any future readers?

Answer (score 0):

This is js code, nearest I found on my computer. It works fine.

```
Ball.prototype.intersects = function (p) {
    'use strict';
    switch (p.id) {
    case IDS.Ball:
        var dist = this.radius + p.radius,
            dx = this.x - p.x, //x - is center of Ball
            dy = this.y - p.y;
        return dist * dist >= (dx * dx + dy * dy);
    default:
        throw "Ball does not provide intersects for " + p.id;
    }
};
```

Also C++ code, I found on my computer. It also works fine

```
bool Ball::intersects(Ball &b) {
    if (this != &b) {
        int dx = b.x - this->x;  //x is center of Ball
        int dy = b.y - this->y;
        int sqrdist = dx*dx + dy*dy;
        int sumrad = b.radius + this->radius;
        return sumrad*sumrad >= sqrdist;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It also works fine. So I suggest that you calculate position of balls before check for intersection.
P.S. And please, distinguish method to check intersection, which return bool. Do not mix checking of event with action on event.

Answer (score 0):

I just inserted your code snippet on a similar collision detection method in one of my games and it worked as expected.

However, i remember i ran into a similar issue when i was testing mine, the issue was with the image displaying, not the collision detection. If you are using LWJGL or something like that for rendering, check that your textures/images are of a power of two size. Sometimes, they just add padding to the nearest power of two and it "seems" like they are not colliding when they actually are, just not visually.